# Create folders in remote server after ssh login using commands

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, amazon-ec2

I need to create folders on the remote server, i try to ssh to the server and then create folders.
The logs display that the ssh is successful but it stops after that and the screen stays at the home folder after
remote login.

Below is the command which i tried to execute but could not find a way out.

```
    def create_folder(key_path,theme)
      system("ssh -i #{key_path}key_file.pem ubuntu@ec2-**-***-**-***.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com ;
          mkdir #{app.name}.git ; cd #{app.name}.git ; git init --bare  ; exit ")
    end
```

Please help

Comment: Check if you have sufficient rights to execute the script. Then check if the script is executable. Try issuing some equivalent commands by hand to see what happens.

Comment: i resolved using the below ans..thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply the command at the end of the ssh

```
ssh user@host command
```

So your command would look something like this

```
ssh  -i #{key_path}key_file.pem ubuntu@ec2-**-***-**-***.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com mkdir appname.git
```

I noticed that you are trying to initialize a git repo. A simpler way to do it is just git init --bare #{app.name}.git

```
ssh  -i #{key_path}key_file.pem ubuntu@ec2-**-***-**-***.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com git init --bare #{app.name}.git
```

Comment: Thanx it worked :)